# Question about seemingly random indentations after compiling

Tags: tables, spacing, errors

So I have been working on a large, 360+ page document, and after working on a few pages of tables, the tables have begun to indent with no apparent reason. Now I don't consider myself a nooby here, but I can't seem to find the reason behind this error. I always compile each page independently and then with the large file to ensure consistency. The tables looked great until today when I added 3 more pages of tables. To check my table code I compiled it separately from the large document, which came out perfect. I fear no amount of MWE will suffice to help with this problem. I have already suppressed indent globally.

My question then is are there some well known mistakes in code that offset the typeset boxes after compilation? Is there an error check I can run? Is there some kind of delimiter I can use to isolate the typesetting on a particular page?

Here are a couple images which show the tables compiled independently, and then in the large document.

[image: Compiled Independently]

[image: Compiled in Large Document]

EDIT: So here is a MWE of the table working independently. In the photo above compiled independently I compiled it with my full preamble. This MWE doesn't include all the options that are seen in the full document.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,openright]{memoir}

\usepackage[bmargin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color, colortbl, longtable}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[%
    linecolor=black,
    outerlinewidth=1pt
    skipabove=0.5\baselineskip,
    skipbelow=0.5\baselineskip,
]{ansbox}

\newcounter{anskeycount}
\setcounter{anskeycount}{0}
\newcommand{\akc}{\small\stepcounter{anskeycount}\theanskeycount}

\begin{document}

\newpage
% \newgeometry{hmargin=.5in}
\begin{ansbox}[
    userdefinedwidth=\textwidth,
    backgroundcolor=black!20]

    \centering \Huge 
    Lower Level ISEE -- Answer Key
\end{ansbox}


\setcounter{anskeycount}{0}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{r|*{17}{C{2.9mm}|}} 

\hline
\rowcolor{black!15}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{Section One}}                          &   
\multicolumn{17}{c|}{\textbf{Part One - Synonyms}} \\ 
% \cline{1-18}
\cline{1-18}
Question \#     &   
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc &  
\akc \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer  & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A \\
\cline{2-18}
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   \\[5pt]
\hline
\rowcolor{black!15}
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{\textbf{Section One}}                                      &   
\multicolumn{17}{c|}{\textbf{Part Two - Sentence Completions}} \\ 
\cline{1-18}
Question \#     &   
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc & 
\akc &  
\akc \\
\cline{2-18}
Correct Answer  &   
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A & 
A \\
\cline{2-18}
Your Answer     & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &   \\[5pt]
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Scores}}                    &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{black!15}\textbf{Correct}}           &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\cellcolor{black!15}\textbf{Total}}             &   
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}            &   
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}    \\
\cline{2-9}
                        &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}   &   
\multicolumn{4}{c|}{34} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}    &   
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}    \\
\cline{2-9}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that generates (potentially just one) of these tables?

Comment: In the second image there's obviously a `\centering` in action. Possibly a missing closing brace.

Comment: isn't it just wider so indented less when centred? (you really need to make an example of the _bad_ tables.

Comment: I have a theory, which may speak to my inexperience with TeX. Can you use `\centering{text}` or is it only proper to use as `{\centering text}. I remember I did the former in my document a while back in places which may explain the centering issue.

Comment: `\centering` doesn't take an argument so that sets `text` in a group and makes that and all the following text centred until the end of the document or surrounding group

Comment: Ok. You are both correct - @egreg and @David Carlisle - on the diagnosis. It is a centering issue. I simple solved the issue using `\raggedright` declaration. Stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: @egreg an answer? TL?

Comment: @cmhughes Probably the best is that the question be removed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved in the comments by diagnosing a use of `centering`